# dataTable column rendering

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, datatable

I have a JSON data structure like this comes from server side:

```
"data":[
    { "subdata":{ "type":"RY", "config":{ "cash":200} }
    { "subdata":{ "type":"SR", "config":{ "cash":200, "chips":300} }
    { "subdata":{ "type":"SR", "config":{ "chips":300} }
    { "subdata":{ "type":"RY", "config":{ "bonus":200, "chips":400} }
    { "subdata":{ "type":"SR", "config":{ "bonus":100} }
]
```

It renders into table in the view like this:

```
<table id='table-config'>
    <tr><td>RY</td> <td>cash=200,</td> <td>Mode Amount=200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>SR</td> <td>cash=200,chips=300,</td> <td>Mode Amount=300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>SR</td> <td>chips=200,</td> <td>Mode Amount=200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RY</td> <td>bonus=200,chips=400,</td> <td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>SR</td> <td>bonus=100,</td> <td>Mode Amount=600</td></tr>
</table>
```

While rendering the data,

First column data should give `type=RY/SR`, but the first cell is coming null after throwing warning like

> DataTables warning (table id = 'table-configs'): Requested unknown parameter 'subdata.type' from the data source for row 0,

Second column data should give the config object, but the second cell is coming null after throwing warning like

> DataTables warning (table id = 'table-configs'): Requested unknown parameter 'subdata.config' from the data source for row 0,

For the third column rendering data is working.

The dataTable js code is:

```
function renderAmount(o, config){
    var amount = '';
    $.each(config, function(key, value){
        amount += key + '=' + value + ',';
    });
    return amount;
}

function renderGameMode(o, data){
    var game_mode= (data.type=='RY')? 'cash' : 'chips';
    var mode_value='';
    $.each(data.config, function(key,value){
        if(key == game_mode){
            mode_value = "Mode Amount="+data.config.key;
        }
    });
    return mode_value;
}

$('#table-configs').dataTable({
    'aaData': data.data,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'aoColumns':[
        { 'mDataProp': 'subdata.type' },
        { 'mDataProp': 'subdata.config', 'fnRender': renderAmount },
        { 'mDataProp': 'subdata', 'fnRender': renderGameMode }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thank You VisioN & LazyTarget. :-)

Comment: You can reply to a person by using the @ symbol @PRADEEP

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong in the code you posted here @Pradeep. Shouldn't it be something like

```
<tr><td>cash=200,</td></tr>
<tr><td>cash=200,chips=300,</td></tr>
<tr><td>chips=200,</td></tr>
<tr><td>bonus=200,chips=400,</td></tr>
<tr><td>bonus=100,</td></tr>
```

If it's not, then maybe that is the problem with the code!

Comment: Sir, As u said..your code is only the output...but problem is not with rendering. its with filtering

Comment: Check firebug in firefox and see if you get any errors therein. Many a times, issues in json formatting leads to data table behaving weirdly, so check on that as well.